# Javascript - Removing part of url with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I may have URLs like:

- http://193.198.112.125/foo/bar/
- http://www.site.com/foo/bar/
- http://193.198.112.125:4000/foo/bar/

and what I would like to do is to remove part before **/foo/bar/**, with regex which will work if I have IP/something, IP:PORT/something or DOMAIN/something

Tnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have always absolute URLs (beginning with the URL scheme), try this:

```
url.replace(/^[^\/]*(?:\/[^\/]*){2}/, "")
```